# How to make sure nothing is in middle of execution in node, before restarting node

Tags: node.js, process

Whenever I restart Node, I have to check nginx access.log whether requests are coming or not.

I don't know there is something that is in the middle of execution.
How can I check it on Linux?

I already checked ps -ef|grep node, top |grep node etc
but again can't say something is in middle of execution.

Comment: I'm wondering if you can just close the server.  That will stop it from accepting new connections.  Existing connections will continue to run until they finish.  Then, if you have no other things keeping node.js running (timers, other connected sockets, etc...) when the last http request in process finishes, node.js will exit on its own.  Would that work?

Comment: From inside your server, you can use `server.getConnections(...)` to get the number of currently active connections, though doing something when you get a zero count back is probably slightly racy.

Comment: Thanks, But is there any terminal command the can tell, the same

Comment: Not that I know of.  But, you could build an API into your server that lets you query or control this.  I should mention that if you're only going to drop by here once every four days, then stackoverflow won't work very well for you.  It's meant to be an interactive place where questions are asked and answered fairly quickly and when people respond you reply back fairly quickly.  It's different than some online internet forums where you might post and then come back a few days later.